# HTTPS not redirecting when using URL but works when typing IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, apache2, amazon-elb

I have this problem. It seems that when I access "foo.com" it doesn't force https. But when I access the IP address of "foo.com" (e.g 54.54.54.54) it forces to "https://54.54.54.54". Please take note that I do have a AWS classic load-balancer and both instances when accessed via IP address returns https. With that, it seems that my .htaccess is working. May I know if there's something that I missed?

Comment: need you htaccess content and your apache2 virtualHost conf content to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the problem at the load balancer level with an Application Load Balancer. It supports redirecting the traffic from http to https in the routing configuration.